# TensorFlow not loading cuDNN

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I have finally managed to get CUDA to work on a Microsoft Azure server with a Kesla T80. Now I need to get cuDNN to work, but TensorFlow won't load it.

This is the message from TensorFlow:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.Session()

2017-04-27 13:05:51.476251: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-27 13:05:51.476306: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-27 13:05:51.476338: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-27 13:05:51.476366: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-27 13:05:51.476394: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-04-27 13:05:58.164781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID ad52:00:00.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.11GiB
2017-04-27 13:05:58.164822: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-04-27 13:05:58.164835: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-04-27 13:05:58.164853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: ad52:00:00.0)
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7fc3c76c0050>
```

So I see there is no cuDNN libraries being loaded.

I have the proper files in `/cuda-8.0/include/` and `/cuda-8.0/lib64/`

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/ | grep "cudnn"
cudnn.h

$ ls /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/ | grep "cudnn"
libcudnn.so
libcudnn.so.5
libcudnn.so.5.1.10
libcudnn_static.a
```

My `~/.bashrc` file has the proper paths

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda8.0
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

**EDIT**
Changed the `.bashrc`to:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/include:${PATH}
```

Still no luck.

Output from nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | AD52:00:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   71C    P0    61W / 149W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |     24%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using tensorflow version 1.1.0, Ubuntu 16.04 and CUDA 8.0.

**EDIT**

So I just tried to delete the cudnn files and load tensorflow, which gave me an error. Something along couldn't finde libcuddn.so.5. So I think it loads it, but I was of the impression that TensorFlow will write something along with "libcuddn.so loaded successfully" if it used cuDNN.

Comment: How did you install tensorflow, use pip or from source code.

Comment: @KrisRoofe using pip.

Comment: are you set up the cudnn path manually. If so you may need to add the lib and include path to  user environmrnt variable.

Comment: Those in the .bashrc file? Yes.

Comment: check if you have this path  /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include

Comment: I've changed the .bashrc to include that without any luch. See my edit.

Comment: your cuda path is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 not /usr/local/cuda

Comment: Okay, but I still have all the files listed in /usr/local/cuda-8.0 as well as the correct directories in PATH: /usr/local/cuda-8.0:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to /usr/local/cuda, not cuda-8; that might be it.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I've also added the /usr/local/cuda-8.0 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH without any success. Do you know if it might be due to compability problems between TF 1.1.0 and cuDNN v. 5.1?

Comment: Maybe cudnn is working for you after all. Maybe try running an op from tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn and see whether it works?

Comment: I fixed it by downgrading to TensorFlow 1.0.1 :)